# Унифицированный способ хранения данных

Tags: хранение-данных

Есть колонка в таблице бд, и в ней я хочу хранить несколько различных значений, ну и чтобы в конечном итоге до этих значений был удобный доступ, как вариант припустим создать массив и сериализировать его и в таком виде хранить, но в таком случае доступность будет зависеть от конкретного ЯП и его реализации сериализации, какую можно выбрать альтернативу? Я думаю XML или есть еще что-то?

Comment: >Есть колонка в таблице бд, и в ней я хочу хранить несколько различных значений

В 99,9999% случаев так делать не стоит. Или, другими словами, количество ситуаций, в которых это может быть оправдано, исчезающе мало.

Comment: то есть в место одной колонки где будут лежать в принципе относительно не очень важные данные (в плане связи их с остальными данными), лучше создать в таблице еще припустим около 10 колонок?

Comment: @Jeremen1, другими словами Вы хотите держать в СУБД значения переменных программы (возможно в разное время) и иметь к ним доступ через SQL?

Опишите всю задачу поподробнее. Просто на Ваш вопрос в текущем виде хочется дать ответ:


   Это бред.

--

Comment: может проще сделать внешний ключ и подчиненную таблицу?
правда если это очень серьезно увеличит количество записей и соответственно сократит скорость, то лучше конечно xml. если СУБД Oracle, то там, по моему, даже были специальные средства для работы с такими ячейками

Comment: @avp сайт БД по игре, там есть различные персонажи, у персонажей есть статы, жизни ,урон, защита и т.д.

Comment: а если для одного персонажа будут нужны два параметра одновременно, тогда что?
Предлагаю свой вариант. Заводится таблица "характеристик", где просто перечислены различные характеристики+id. Отдельно заводиться таблица из таких полей - id персонажа, id характеристики, значение характеристики. Таким образом решается сразу много проблем - один персонаж может иметь много характеристик, а может и не одной. Память при этом не тратиться. В таблице характеристик могут быть описаны "единицы измерения".

Comment: @Jeremen1, начните с проектирования логической структуры данных и ее представления в виде таблиц СУБД. 

А уже потом переходите к ее представлению в структурах данных программы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно хранить <жизнь>, <урон>, <защита> и подобное — то можно в той же таблице персонажей:

```
id | name  | health | power | defence
 1 | Some  |    100 |     2 |       3
 2 | Other |     78 |     2 |       3
```

И в большинстве случаев это лучший вариант.

А вот когда дойдет дело, скажем, до вещмешка, то его содержимое нужно хранить в отдельной таблице, причем сначала нужно составить таблицу всех возможных единиц:

```
id | name
 1 | Отвертка
 2 | Ключ
 3 | Разводной ключ
```

А потом сделать таблицу связей (у кого что есть):

```
id | person_id | item_id | quantity
 1 |         1 |       1 |        2
 2 |         2 |       3 |        1
 3 |         1 |       2 |        3
```

Выходит, что знаешь, у кого какие есть инструменты и в каком количестве (иногда есть смысл вместо указания количества `quantity` просто добавлять еще одну строку, но это некошерно).

Получается, что ты можешь узнать с помощью одного простого запроса, у кого сколько здоровья, силы и прочее. А когда нужно будет получить содержимое вещмешка персонажа (у тебя есть его `id` персонажа), нужно будет выполнить 1 запрос со склейкой (ну или с подзапросом), в результате ты получишь вот это:

```
id | person_id | item_id | quantity | item_name | item_quantity
 1 |         1 |       1 |        2 | Отвертка  |             2
 3 |         1 |       2 |        3 | Ключ      |             3
```

То есть, у персонажа #1 по имени Some есть 2 отвертки и 3 ключа.